# Custom Button : Conditional Redirect to URL using Javascript

Tags: custom-button

[image: URL Image]
I am connecting to the URL by using custom button when Update__c = true condition reamin all conditions these button connect to different URL. but when i used 
below code it showing URL Breaks, but the URl is working.I placed this code in Buttons Section.
 but IN URL it showing like that

https://na15.salesforce.com/servlet/if(%27true%27%20==%20%27true%27)%7B%20%20%20%20window.location.href%20=%20%27/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?id=a00i000000KtP5X%27%20;}

```
 if('{!Quote__c.Updated__c}' == 'true')
 {
   window.location.href = '/_ui/core/email/author/ EmailAuthor?id={!Quote__c.Id}' ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute JavaScript when the button is clicked (for your conditional logic), you need to use the "Execute JavaScript" and "OnClick JavaScript" options.

Comment: when i click the email button it is not connecting to link which i was provide.Showing in Pop-up UNexpected Token Illegal.

Comment: @Sathya Based on your screen shot you appear to have put a line break in the middle of the JavaScript string. Ensure that this "window.location.href = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?id={!Quote__c.Id}';" is all on one line.

Comment: Right Now i am checking the Quote__c.Update__c = true, but i want to check the Quote_Line__c.Update__c = true at that time only email button action have to perform.

Comment: @Sathya Then your JavaScript will have to reference the input field itself to use the current value (rather than the value when the page was rendered).

Comment: Can you give suggestions where i have to update my javascript code.

Comment: if('{!Quote__c.Updated__c}'  && {!Quote_line__c.Updated__c}'== 'true')
 {
   window.location.href = '/_ui/core/email/author/ EmailAuthor?id={!Quote__c.Id}' ;
} but it is not working.

Comment: @Sathya Probably best that you ask a separate question. I was saying that you would need to use document.getElementById to access the current value of the form field.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33451/email-button-connect-to-url-based-upon-condition can you check this URL i placed as a new question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14086/discussion-between-sathya-and-keith-c)

Answer (score 3):

```
<apex:page>
<div id="output"></div>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js"/>
<script>
    sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

    function setupPage() {

        var output = document.getElementById("output");
            alert(output);
        var startTime = new Date().getTime()

         try {
            var queryResult = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Name,Industry From Account ");
            layoutResults(queryResult, output, startTime);
        } catch(error) {
            queryFailed(error, output);
        }
    }

    function queryFailed(error, out) {
        out.innerHTML = "<font color=red>An error has occurred:</font> <p>" + error;
    }

    function layoutResults(queryResult, out, startTime) {
        var timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

        if (queryResult.size > 0) {
            var output = "";
            var records = queryResult.getArray('records');

            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                var account = records[i];
                output += account.Id + " " + account.Name + " [Industry - "  
                     + account.Industry + "]<BR>";
            }

            out.innerHTML = output + "<BR> <BR> query complexted in: " + timeTaken + " ms.";
        } else {
            out.innerHTML = "No records matched.";
        }
    }
    window.onload=setupPage();
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Riaz, one has to be careful when posting code. I've fixed your post. The first 6 lines and last 2 weren't displayed. Be sure to space over at least 4 spaces. Unfortunately, pasting all of your code in at once using the "preformatted text" braces doesn't always retain your spacing/tabbing, so best to check that in a preview pane before saving.

Answer (score 0):

On button creation page choose option as URL. Which lies above the formulae box.

Comment: i selecet URL once can you check image oce in my question